# Problem loading a Neo4J database from a dump on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I made a dump of my local Neo4J database and then launched an AWS instance with Neo4J and I'm trying to run that same database there. Both are versions 3.5.14.

When I launch the local Neo4j AWS instance after it's just set up, it's launches fine and is accessible via bolt.

However, then I stop that instance using `systemctl stop neo4j` and attempt to load my dumped database onto AWS using the command

`neo4j-admin load ....`

(which works)

However, when I launch the database again after using `systemctl start neo4j` it just stops and restarts and cannot launch.

The datastore should not be upgraded as it's the same version, so I don't see what the problem may be.

Just in case, I uncommented the datastore upgrade in
`/etc/neo4j/neo4j.template`

But that doesn't help either.

Could you please advise me what else I could do?

Comment: try to see what the logs show. usually they have important clues as to what is going on. Here is the page which gives you log file location, and if the neo4j is running under debian based distros, how to generate neo4j.log . https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions on dumping and loading](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/#neo4j-admin-dump-load)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Followed them to the word. And it's still not working...

Comment: @cybersam the only thing I don't understand in the instructions is how to run `neo4j-admin` as a `neo4j` user? Don't we just run it from the linux command string?

Comment: If you had no errors running the command, then that should not be an issue. Try checking the logs, as suggested above by @blackrain.